# How to get subplot titles from a list or automatically from the data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, subplot, yahoo-finance

I have this code:

```
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import pyfolio as pf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

myStartDate = "2019-1-1"   # (Format: Year-Month-Day)
myEndDate = "2020-11-11"   # (Format: Year-Month-Day)
myTickers = ["AAPL", "MSFT"]

myData = pdr.get_data_yahoo(myTickers, myStartDate, myEndDate)

myDailyAdjustedClose = myData[['Adj Close']]
returns = myDailyAdjustedClose.pct_change()

returnsColumnCount = returns.shape[1]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(returnsColumnCount, 1, figsize=(10, 10))
fig.tight_layout(pad=5)

for x in range(returnsColumnCount):
    columnData = returns.iloc[:, x]
    pf.plot_drawdown_underwater(columnData, ax=ax[x])

plt.show();
```

But all the plots are simply named "Undewater Plot." If I add this "ax[x].set_title('Test')" to the for loop I can change all the titles to "Test." I want the plots to be named after the "myTickers" list. So the first plot would be named "AAPL" and the 2nd plot would be named "MSFT"]... etc... Do I have to index through the "myTickers" list? or is there a more elegant way? Something like "ax.set_title(myTickers)"... Or perhaps automatically getting them from the returns data?

Comment: I suppose you should be able to use the `x` within the for loop as an index for the ticker list, i.e. `ax[x].set_title(myTickers[x])`, assuming that the order of tickers is not changed throughout the script.

Comment: Ok... Thanks... I was going to look into doing it that way. Just thought there might be a better way.